# PHP-SQL - populate a dynamic filter list

Tags: php, sql, navicat

I am trying to :

- Display products based on a location selection
- loop through products and return column names that = 1 (true)
- Create a products filter drop-down containing these column names that represent product features

At the moment, the filter dropdown contains by default all columns, in some scenarios ( based on the selected location ) this is okay on the other hand, if a location has only two products out of the 20 it is annoying to display in the filter drop-down features that are irrelevant and that will return no-result...

This is a brief example of what I am trying to say ;

**Database Table structure**

`+------+------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| SKU  |   HDMI     |      3D     |   Android      |  Ethernet   |   location  |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
|TV1X  |     0      |      0      |     0          |      0      |all          |
|TV5X  |     0      |      0      |     0          |      0      |fr uk usa    |
|TV3Z  |     1      |      0      |     0          |      1      |usa          |
|TVH3  |     1      |      1      |     1          |      1      |mex          |
|TVH1  |     1      |      1      |     1          |      1      |fr es uk     |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+`

Features columns are of type `bit`

**Product display**

Let's say `$location = "%".'usa'."%"`

```
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `location` LIKE :location" ;
$statement = $dbh->prepare($queryString)
$statement->bindParam(':location',  $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

The query above will return `TV5X` & `TV3Z`which are related to USA, these products features that are 'TRUE' are `HDMI` + `Ethernet` only where the remaining two columns I do not wish to display in the filter dropdown. This example might be more relevant when we many products/features and locations...

**Default Filter List**

```
<li >
  <button  data-filter=".HDMI" >HDMI</button>
</li>
<li >
  <button  data-filter=".3D" >3D</button>
</li>
<li >
  <button  data-filter=".Android" >Android OS</button>
</li>
<li >
  <button  data-filter=".Ethernet" >Ethernet</button>
</li>
```

The default filter list is relevant to some countries but not USA

**Dynamic Filter List**

Based on the retrieved products (two in this case), query the db and find which columns for these products have TRUE as value.

```
<?php  foreach( $feature as $feat) : ?>

 <li >
    <button  data-filter=".<?php print  //Col_Name   ;?>" ><?php print  ect..    ;?></button>
 </li>

<?php endforeach;  ?>
```

I apologize for the long post, I am trying to explain the best way I can.

**My question is how do build a query for this purpose ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in one additional query by selecting the sum of each column and then checking that the returned value is > 0:

```
SELECT SUM(`HDMI`) AS `HDMI`,
       SUM(`3D`) AS `3D`,
       SUM(`Android`) AS `Android`,
       SUM(`Ethernet`) AS `Ethernet`
FROM `products`
WHERE `location` LIKE :location
```

Run this query after your first query, and the code to output the filter list simply becomes this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $column => $numProducts) {
        if ($numProducts > 0) { // i.e., SUM($column) is > 0
            $html .= "<li>
                <button data-filter=\".{$column}\">{$column} ({$numProducts})</button>
            </li>";
        }
    }
}
```

This also has the added bonus of giving you the number of products which have each feature. :)